# How to find all positive integer solutions of this tricky system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, integers

What are all tuples off postive integers w,x,y,z that fullfill following system of equations:

$$ x + 10z^2 = 2014 $$
$$ 2y + z = 54$$
$$ (y+2x + \frac{7}{2}w)z=1211$$

I am really lost - all my attemps lead into disaster..

Comment: I did not understand. $z$ - is always even. this follows from the 2 equations.  and you have 3 odd equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use basic detective work. From the second equation, $z$ is even. Now look at the first equation $x+10z^2=2014$. Since $z$ is even and positive, there are not many possibilities for $z$. For already at $z=20$ we have $10z^2$ is quite a bit bigger than $2014$.

So there are not many cases to check. A bit grungy, but you will soon arrive at the solution.

By the way, $1211=(7)(173)$. If you think about this, you will arrive at the answer in one step.

Comment: wow. Now I feel really stupid ;) but thank you very much - that's perfect!

Comment: You are welcome. I started with the "grungy" approach in order to stress that educated fooling around is a perfectly respectable way to solve a problem. But I could not resist adding the "quickie" $1211=(7)(173)$ observation.